# Populate Spinner WITHOUT Strings.xml file

Tags: java, android, android-layout, spinner, android-spinner

So everything I have found is using the strings.xml file to populate a spinner. What I want to do is populate a spinner based on information I get back from a JSON response. I have the following code that I used to populate a table but modified it for this. However, my spinner is still blank and I get no errors besides `D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null`

Here is the code to populate the spinner:

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment implements APIRequestsUtil.APIRequestResponseListener
{
    View myView;
    Map<String, Route> drives;
    private ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_layout, container, false);
        APIRequestsUtil.setOnNetWorkListener(this);
        return myView;
    }

    private void populateView() {
        this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                drives = APIRequestsUtil.getRoutes();

                Spinner spinner = (Spinner) myView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                int driveNum = 0;
                for (Map.Entry drive : drives.entrySet()) {
                    TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
                    Route route = (Route) drive.getValue();
                    tr.setId(driveNum++);
                    //tr.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



                    spinner.setId(driveNum);

                }
            }
        });

    }

    //@Override
    public void onFailure(Request request, Throwable throwable) {

    }

    //@Override
    public void onResponse(Response response) {
        populateView();
    }
}
```

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So everything I have found is using the strings.xml file to populate a spinner.

[Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Selection/Spinner) that demonstrates populating a `Spinner` with the contents of a Java array.

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) happens to use an array resource for populating the `Spinner`, but you could swap in some other `ArrayAdapter` for the one their sample code creates using `createFromResource()`.

> Here is the code to populate the spinner

There is no code in there that populates a `Spinner`. You retrieve a `Spinner` from your layout. You then call `setId()` on it in a loop — I am not completely clear why. You have an `ArrayAdapter` named `adapter` that holds promise, but you never set it up.

Here is the activity from the sample app that I linked to above:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2008-2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain   a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
*/

package com.commonsware.android.selection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SpinnerDemo extends Activity
  implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
  private TextView selection;
  private static final String[] items={"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor",
          "sit", "amet",
          "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi", "vel",
          "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis",
          "etiam", "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante",
          "porttitor", "sodales", "pellentesque", "augue", "purus"};

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);

    Spinner spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                              android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                              items);

    aa.setDropDownViewResource(
      android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin.setAdapter(aa);
  }

  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View v, int position, long id) {
    selection.setText(items[position]);
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    selection.setText("");
  }
}
```

It follow the same recipe as in the documentation. I happen to use a constructor to create the `ArrayAdapter` instance, wrapping it around the `String[]` that is my model data. It is unclear what you want to have in your `Spinner`, but you could have an `ArrayAdapter<Integer>` (as is shown in your code) or `ArrayAdapter<Route>` or whatever.

For more complex scenarios, look for `ListView` examples. `Spinner` works nearly identically, with only two substantial changes:

- You need to provide two layout resources (see `setDropDownViewResource()` in the code above). And, if you override `getView()` in a custom subclass of `ArrayAdapter`, probably you also need to override `getDropDownView()`.
- `Spinner` fires selection events, not item click events

Comment: I would use a listview but I need a drop down because using a listview would be way too much going on on the page.

Comment: @JamesRobertSingleton: That's fine. My point is that `Spinner` works a lot like `ListView`. `ListView` is also substantially more popular. So, if you are having difficulty finding an example of doing something with a `Spinner`, find an example of doing that same thing with a `ListView`, and it should give you clues for how to implement it with your `Spinner`.

Comment: that example has  private static final String[] items={"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", etc etc}. I don't want to set those values though.

Comment: @JamesRobertSingleton: Then come up with your own values and use whichever `ArrayAdapter` constructor that you want to use.