# Empty Spinner in fragment | Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, fragment

I am trying to show values in spinner from Arrayadapter in one of my fragments in the *onCreateView* in my public *final class Manual extends Fragment*:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View vista =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pag1,container,false);
   fragment pag1
    calcular= (Button)vista.findViewById(R.id.button);
    etd=(EditText)vista.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    resultadocp=(TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    lista = (Spinner)vista.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    String []opciones={"one","two","three","four","five"};

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, opciones);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);    return vista;  }
```

i don´t understand why when runs aplication, this spinner shows empty

Comment: You can look at the answer to my spinner question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39302077/populate-spinner-without-strings-xml-file/39302220?noredirect=1#comment65938702_39302220

Answer (score 0):

Declare The Array Like this:

```
private static final String[] opciones={"one","two","three","four","five"};
```

The Spinner Code Here Should be like:-

```
    Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                              android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                              opciones);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: This doesn´t work, im on fragment, i need the view "vista" lista = (Spinner)vista.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

Comment: just add vista.findViewById there rest all is same, and it will work

Comment: Sorry but, im trying with your code and doesn´t works :( the spinner dont change